# JPA: query for all items in a list where target is also a list

Tags: jpa

I have two entities:

1. Engineer - has a set of tags (say skillsets - Java. .NET, etc.)
2. Tag

An engineer may have any number of tags. And a tag is associated with any number of engineers.

```
@Entity
public class Engineer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Tag> tags;

    /* Getters and Setters */
}

@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String name;

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Now, I want to query for engineers who have a list of tags associated with them. For example - "Query for engineers with tags 'Java', 'Opensource', and 'Banking'". The query should return engineers who have all the tags associated with them.

I am able to query for one tag:

```
public List<Engineer> searchMindsByTags(String tag) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Engineer e WHERE '" + tag
            + "' = ANY(SELECT tag.name FROM e.tags tag)");
    return (List<Engineer>) q.getResultList();
}
```

What I need is:

```
public List<Engineer> searchMindsByTags(List<String> tags) {
    /* Which query goes here? */
}
```

Is there a single query which can do this job or do we need iterate over the results progressively to filter?

Comment: 1. I think you need @ManyToMany mapping.
2. Why you don't iterrate over all elements in tags list in second query and use AND for each condition?

Answer (score 1):

> An engineer may have any number of tags. And a tag is associated with any number of engineers.

You entity design contradicts above requirement.

You modelled Engineer having one to many relationship to Tag. Hence on a tag table you would see a foreign key column `engineer_id`. Ie: a tag is associated to one (and only 1) engineer.

You need to model the relationship as many to many with join tables. Engineer entity class should have Tag collection decorated with `@ManyToMany`, Tag entity class should have an Engineer collection decorated with `@ManyToMany`.

Using the Engineer collection on Tag class you can implement your `searchMindsByTags` functions

Comment: I will try with ManytoMany but can you please tell me what would be the query to use in this case?

Comment: You don't event need a criteria query, you can just combine the engineer collection on each tag object. Of course this is less efficient because each time engineer collection is accessed it will translate into 1 SQL

Comment: Then don't see advantage in making it ManyToMany. We can as well iterate over the list. Just to be clear, Tag entity will not have Engineers as an attribute.

Comment: If you don't make it many to many then how are you going to satisfy "a tag is associated with any number of engineer"? As soon as a tag is attached to one engineer, you can't attach it to a different engineer (the `engineer id` FK column can only reference 1 engineer)

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is that you can construct your query with something like this:

```
public List<String> searchMindsByTags(List<String> tags)
{

    String queryString = "SELECT e FROM Engineer e ";
    List<Tag> tagobjects=null;
    if (tags != null && !tags.isEmpty()) {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("Select t from tag t where t.name IN :tags");
        q.setParameter("tags", tags);
        tagobjects = q.getResultList();
        queryString += " WHERE ";
        for (int i = 0; i < tagobjects.size(); i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                queryString += "AND ";
            }
            queryString += "?" + (i + 1) + " member of e.tags";
        }
    }
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    if (tagobjects != null && !tagobjects.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tagobjects.size(); i++) {
            q.setParameter((i + 1), tagobjects.get(i));
        }
    }
    return (List<Engineer>) q.getResultList();
}
```

Its quick example, needs some testing.

Comment: I dont think this works. I tested a straight query: `SELECT e FROM Engineers e JOIN e.tags tag WHERE tag.name='Drools' AND tag.name='Eclipse'`. How can tag.name have both names?

Comment: Sorry I fixed my method

Comment: Sorry I have discovered another bug, had to fix it again, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use multiple sub selects, or use a count.

See,
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Subselect.2C_querying_a_to_many_relationship_where_all_of_the_relations_are_in_a_list